# Jenkins json stringify data on different format

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I am facing an issue on my client machine, when i store stringify data in hiddenfield of jenkins and look in config.xml it is different on my side and my client side.

I use same environment and jenkins version but not reproduce on my side.

My config.xml

```
<hiddenfieldforGlobalVariables>&quot;[{\&quot;GVName\&quot;: \&quot;environment\&quot;, \&quot;GVValue\&quot;: \&quot;Wm5WamF3\&quot;, \&quot;GVType\&quot;: \&quot;String\&quot;}]&quot;</hiddenfieldforGlobalVariables>
```

Client Side config.xml

```
<hiddenfieldforGlobalVariables>[{"GVName":"environment","GVValue":"ZnVjaw==","GVType":"String"}]</hiddenfieldforGlobalVariables>
```

What is the problem? Need help! Cant understand.

Comment: are you using hidden parameter plugin????

Comment: No iam not using hidden parameter plugin, but my plugin has some hidden fields

Comment: did you write your own plugin???? I've seen the hidden fields in my local using hidden parameter plugin. Thats as per your local config only. not like your client side.

Comment: Yes i write my own plugin, and i set json value in that hidden field

Comment: your client system os?? your system os?? how did you save the json field to config??